# Can't establish an internet connection in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I've tried using the method in arch linux beginners' guide, under 2. Install, 2.2.1 Wired, but it didn't work, granted there's one step I didn't quite understand, which is the last step:

```
Edit resolv.conf, substituting your name servers' IP addresses and your local domain   name:
```

I don't think that method would've worked, since it says it's for if you have a static IP, but my ISP assigned me a dynamic one.

I've also tried `systemctl stop dhcpcd.service`, `ip link set *myethernetdev* up`, `systemctl start dhcpcd@*myethernetdev*`. That gave me an error, but I never wrote it down. If anyone could help me out here, I would really appreciate it, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your DNS to `/etc/resolv.conf`, not your external IP address. You are free to use Google's DNS, so you contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` should be as following:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Other than that, you did not provide any information on how you need to connect to your internet. If you have a router on your network then starting `dhcpcd.service` is usually enough to do assuming there is DHCP server running on your router (which is the case most of the time).

Comment: In /etc/resolv.conf there's also a line that look something like this: search <domain.tld> What do I add in there?

Comment: If your computer is not part of a domain, then comment this line out or remove it, it's not needed. Also, it is likely that `resolv.conf` will be configured/overwritten by `dhcpcd`, so first try only running that.

Comment: Ok, sorry, just want to clarify here. Boot from the CD, `systemctl stop dhcpcd.service`, then `systemctl start dhcpcd@myethernetdev` and then edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file accordingly?

Comment: No. Boot from cd, and execute `systemctl start dhcpd` or just `dhcpcd`. That's it.

Comment: Sorry, should've specified that I've already tried these and they didn't work.